# Default value for abstract class pointer parameter

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism, abstract-class, default-value

I am trying to do something like this:

```
class Movement {
public:
    virtual void move() = 0;
};

class Walk : public Movement {
public:
    void move() { cout << "walking"; }
};

class Run : public Movement {
public:
    void move() { cout << "run"; }
};
```

```
class Animal {
public:
    virtual void print();
};

class Human : public Animal {
public:
    void print() { cout << "Human"; }
};

class Lion : public Animal {
public:
    void print() { cout << "Lion"; }
};
```

```
class Model {
    Animal* animal;
    Movement* movement;

public:
    Model(Animal* animal = new Human(), Movement* movement = new Walk()) {
        this->animal = animal;
        this->movement = movement;
    }
    void print() {
        cout << "This Model consist of one: ";
        animal->print();
        cout << ", which is: ";
        movement->move();
    }
};
```

```
int main() {
    Model first = Model(), second = Model(new Lion(), new Run());
    first.print();
    cout << endl;
    second.print();
    return 0;
}
```

How do we set the default value for abstract class pointers & how to pass them as a parameter like that from main?

I would also prefer to be able to pass arguments from main like this only in a single line without needing to initialize before.

can anyone please help me with how do we such things in C++?

I have tried and searched a lot but no luck.

I am looking for a workaround to do something like this, in which we use an abstract classes as a parameter of other classes.

I know objects cannot be assigned to a pointer, I just don't know what to do there to fulfill my requirement, an abstract class as a parameter with a default value.

This is my latest attempt with exact code, but unfortunately with `new`, does anyone know how to get rid of `new` and achieve the desired outcome?

**Note:**
My actual code is quite complex, basically using an abstract class for polymorphism and pass those abstract classes as parameters to another class with default parameters, if there is **ANY** other way to do something similar I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: please focus one one question per question. If your code has errors, please include the compiler error in the question

Comment: Objects are not pointers, pointers are not objects. There is no way to do anything like this in C++. You could use `new`, but this will obviously leak memory. This looks like Java code, however C++ is not Java.

Comment: In `Animal* animal = Human()`, `Animal* animal` expects a pointer to an `Animal` or something derived from `Animal`. `Human()` does not provide a pointer.

Comment: use overloads instead of default arguments

Comment: I am looking for a workaround to do something like this, not exactly like this, basically how do we do things like this in c++, in which we use abstract classes as parameters for other classes.

Comment: When you declared `Model first()` in `main()`, you declared function `first` returning `Model`. Google "most vexing parse".

Comment: @Eugene sorry I didn't got your points, it would be really helpful if you could elaborate.

Comment: I have edited the question to remove questions thank you for your instant comments. any help will be really helpful.

Comment: Again: do you understand the differences between pointers and objects? You can't create an object and assign it to a pointer, either in a default parameter value, or anywhere else. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik I understand your point I know I cannot do that, this is a pseudo code, there I just want to use abstract class as a parameter and set a default value to it.

Comment: Well, presumably pseudocode will become real code, at some point. And you would still be unable to create an object and assign it to a pointer, because C++ will still not work this way, at that time, either.

Comment: I know I cannot assign an object to parameter, that is why I am asking what to do there, to use the abstract class as a parameter with default values, it does not need to be a pointer there, just whatever achieves the above need.

Comment: "this is a pseudo code" ?!? Why do you care about pseudo code? If you fix the errors in your code then it will compile and do what you want... I am a bit puzzled now, I mean you even have comment in the code indicating compiler errors

Comment: Using a `const` reference, and not a pointer, would work if the object does not need to be modified (since `const` references bind to temporaries). That's the simplest solutions. Other solutions would be a default value of `nullptr`, and have the function itself construct the suitable object in auto scope and then recursively call itself, now supplying a pointer to it.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I don't know how to fix this with also getting the desired outcome, it will really help if you can show how will you fix this code with getting the desired outcome.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yes I have already tried that, but than it gives error in main first and second declaration as no constructor matches with Run and Lion.

Comment: please post a [mcve] and the compiler error message. Your code has syntax errors that are not related to your question

Comment: Unfortunately, code speaks louder than words, and nobody will be able to figure out a problem with code that's not even shown.

Comment: I have added the exact code for minimal reproducable example with no compilation erros .

Comment: @Vishnu You don't need to point out evey single edit in your question. We can see what was [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64093159/revisions) in the question at each revision.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I get what you are trying to say, a pointer to an object is distinct from that object, but a pointer is also an object. So *"pointers are not objects"* is not accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I came up with the best solution for my situation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
```

```
class Movement {
 public:
  virtual void move() = 0;
  virtual unique_ptr<Movement> movement() const = 0;
};

class Walk : public Movement {
 public:
  void move() { cout << "walking"; }
  unique_ptr<Movement> movement() const { return make_unique<Walk>(); }
};

class Run : public Movement {
 public:
  void move() { cout << "run"; }
  unique_ptr<Movement> movement() const { return make_unique<Run>(); }
};
```

```
class Animal {
 public:
  virtual void print() = 0;
  virtual unique_ptr<Animal> animal() const = 0;
};

class Human : public Animal {
 public:
  void print() { cout << "Human"; }
  unique_ptr<Animal> animal() const { return make_unique<Human>(); }
};

class Lion : public Animal {
 public:
  void print() { cout << "Lion"; }
  unique_ptr<Animal> animal() const { return make_unique<Lion>(); }
};
```

```
class Model {
  unique_ptr<Animal> animal;
  unique_ptr<Movement> movement;

 public:
  Model(const Animal& animal = Human(), const Movement& movement = Walk()) {
    this->animal = animal.animal();
    this->movement = movement.movement();
  }
  void print() {
    cout << "This Model consist of one: ";
    animal->print();
    cout << ", which is: ";
    movement->move();
  }
};
```

```
int main() {
  Model first = Model(), second = Model(Lion(), Run());
  first.print();
  cout << endl;
  second.print();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your new `animal` and `movement` methods are traditionally named `clone`. With this name, your source would be easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a design question. In `Model`class design, you either need to decide about the object ownership, or defer the decision to the calling code. In the latter case, you cannot have default arguments (unless you want to have global constants `Human` and `Walk`, but I would not recommend it).

One way to have the default arguments is to decide that `Model` has exclusive ownership of `Animal` and `Movement`, and store `unique_ptr`s to them. Something like this:

```
class Model {
    unique_ptr<Animal> animal;
    unique_ptr<Movement> movement;

public:
  Model(unique_ptr<Animal> animal = make_unique<Human>(), unique_ptr<Movement> movement = make_unique<Walk>()){ 
    this->animal = std::move(animal);
    this->movement = std::move(movement);
  }
  void print() {
    cout << "This Model consist of one: ";
    animal->print();
    cout << ", which is: ";
    movement->move();
  }
};

int main() {
  Model first/*no () here!*/, second(make_unique<Lion>(), make_unique<Run>()); 
  first.print();
  cout << endl;
  second.print();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you. I have updated the answer from your compiled source.

Comment: Np, glad to help. Oops, before we loose the [link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50d2fbad0833e22d) :P

Answer (score -1):

Is your problem the compile error? There are multiple ways to address the compile error, but given that your question is about inheriting from abstract classes, I will focus on that.

First, as provided, your `Animal` class is ***not*** an abstract class. An abstract class cannot be instantiated because all its methods are pure virtual. In C++, pure virtual functions are designated by the `virtual` keyword prefix, ***and*** suffixed by `= 0` in their definition. E.g.

```
...
virtual void print() = 0;
...
```

The following code is compilable by making your `Animal` class an abstract class:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Movement {
 public:
  virtual void move() = 0;
};

class Walk : public Movement {
 public:
  void move() { cout << "walking"; }
};

class Run : public Movement {
 public:
  void move() { cout << "run"; }
};

class Animal {
 public:
  virtual void print() = 0;
};

class Human : public Animal {
 public:
  void print() { cout << "Human"; }
};

class Lion : public Animal {
 public:
  void print() { cout << "Lion"; }
};

class Model {
  Animal* animal;
  Movement* movement;

 public:
  Model(Animal* animal = new Human(), Movement* movement = new Walk()) {
    this->animal = animal;
    this->movement = movement;
  }
  void print() {
    cout << "This Model consist of one: ";
    animal->print();
    cout << ", which is: ";
    movement->move();
  }
};

int main() {
  Model first = Model(),
        second = Model(new Lion(), new Run());
  first.print();
  cout << endl;
  second.print();
  return 0;
}
```

Incidentally, your code can also be made compilable by providing an implementation for `Animal::print()`. The following code is also compilable, but `Animal` ***is not*** an abstract class because it provides an implementation for `Animal::print()` rather than suffixing it with `= 0`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Movement {
 public:
  virtual void move() = 0;
};

class Walk : public Movement {
 public:
  void move() { cout << "walking"; }
};

class Run : public Movement {
 public:
  void move() { cout << "run"; }
};

class Animal {
 public:
  virtual void print() {};
};

class Human : public Animal {
 public:
  void print() { cout << "Human"; }
};

class Lion : public Animal {
 public:
  void print() { cout << "Lion"; }
};

class Model {
  Animal* animal;
  Movement* movement;

 public:
  Model(Animal* animal = new Human(), Movement* movement = new Walk()) {
    this->animal = animal;
    this->movement = movement;
  }
  void print() {
    cout << "This Model consist of one: ";
    animal->print();
    cout << ", which is: ";
    movement->move();
  }
};

int main() {
  Model first = Model(),
        second = Model(new Lion(), new Run());
  first.print();
  cout << endl;
  second.print();
  return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, conceptually, what you're doing is fine and totally possible in C++: assigning a default value to a base class pointer that's in some function's argument list.

---

**Important**: As commenters have correctly pointed out, the pattern you have coded is dangerous: your interface is such that a user can ***optionally*** provide an `Animal` instance. The problem is: if the `Model` creator does, then it can be reasonably argued that he rightly owns the object. If he does not, then your constructor *will* create a new `Animal` instance, but neither does `Model` take ownership of the object, nor does it provide an interface by which the user can take ownership of the new `Animal` instance. This therefore creates a memory leak. Equally, the code hazard, is ambiguous ownership of the `Animal` instance used in the `Model` constructor.

Comment: You should at least mention the memory leak without appropriate deletion in the `Model` destructor (but then you still have the problem of inteterminate ownership).

Comment: the question is about inheriting from an abstract class. OP did not provide a definition for `Animal::print` on purpose